# Return Statuscode Unauthorized from Generic type method

Tags: c#, generics

I have created web api and calling service method from MVC application. I have implemented authentication in Web Api.

I have created Generic type method from which I call my service method and returning result to action method like below:

```
 public async Task < T > GetWSObject < T > (string uriActionString)  
        {  
            T returnValue = default (T);  
            try  
            {  
                using(var client = new HttpClient())  
                {
                    //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50524/"); 
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();  
                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
                   // HttpClient cons = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50524/"); // Web Service URL
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ankita:ankita12");
                    var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(data));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString);                    
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  
                    returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < T > (((HttpResponseMessage) response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);  
                }  
                return returnValue;  
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                throw (e);  
            }  
        }
```

Moreover, I am calling this method from my action method like:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ViewAuthor(Author author)
    {       
            ViewBag.Message = "Your Author page.";
            Author authors = new Author();
            string urlAction = String.Format("api/Authors/GetAuthor/{0}", author.Id);
            authors = await GetWSObject<Author>(urlAction);
            return View(authors);         

    }
```

Now how can I return message from catch block in case of Unauthorized access as GetWSObject method is having generic type.

I just want to display message on my Author detail page like you are unauthorized to perform this action. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices

1. Add a type to wrap the result for example `WSResult<T>`. Then your method will return that type. It can look like this

```
public class WSResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then your method will return this type and consumers will check the status first. This is similar to how HttpResponseMessage works. You can copy ideas from it.

In this case your method has a signature like this

```
public async Task<WSResult<T>> GetWSObject<T> (string uriActionString)
```

You return things from it like this

```
return new WSResult<T> { Result = returnValue, Status = HttpStatusCode.OK }
```

Or in the catch

```
return new WSResult<T> { Result = returnValue, Status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError }
```

Note that the actual status code in the exception may differ and you should catch the proper exception. You can also use a boolean instead of HttpStatusCode and call it IsSuccessful or something. You can also roll your own enum with values suitable for your code.

2. Alternatively you can throw an exception that contains the status code. The second way is easier to implement and requires less refactoring but the first one is the recommended way.

Comment: Agree, just small note, the class itself must be generic: public class WSResult<T> { public T Result {get; set;} public HttpStatusCode StatusCode {get; set;} }

Comment: It is generic for some reason I can't handle the formatter and it treats it as a tag. I will log in with another browser to fix it.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly I need to return. Because it is showing message that can't convert to T type

Comment: OK I am a noob. If someone can fix the formatting in the code sample so that it displays the generic argument of WSResult I'll be grateful.